# Why does XmlPullParserException exception occurs?

Tags: java, android

I try to parse simple xml file with XmlPullParser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<tests>
    <test>
        <name>Jack</name>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>Brad</name>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>Tom</name>
    </test>
</tests>
```

This is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    ArrayList<Quote> quotes;
    ArrayList<Pers> persons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.test);

        Fetcher fetcher = new Fetcher();
        persons = fetcher.parse(inputStream);

        String str = new String();
        for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
            str += persons.get(i).getName();
        }
        Log.d("1", str);
    }
}
```

This is the Fetcher class code:

```
public class Fetcher {
    private ArrayList<Pers> persons;
    private Pers person;
    private String text;

    public Fetcher() {
        persons = new ArrayList<Pers>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Pers> parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch(eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                            person = new Pers();
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                            persons.add(person);
                        } else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                            person.setName(text);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return persons;
    }
}
```

Why does XmlPullParserException exception occurs?

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT ��������������������...@1:49 in java.io.InputStreamReader@405534d8)
```

Comment: Because there's an unterminated entity ref in your XML.

Comment: @Dave Newton May be you have some ideas how to fix this? I will be grateful to you if you can help me.

Comment: How did you create the xml? Did you create a plain text file, or did you use a word processor, copy from a web page, etc? It's likely got some binary or other garbage in it.

Comment: @Dave Newton i created xml file using Android Studio into xml folder. New->Resource xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed code, now it works. Thank those who tried to help me.

```
public class Fetcher {
    private ArrayList<Pers> persons;
    private Pers person;
    private String text;

    public Fetcher() {
        persons = new ArrayList<Pers>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Quote> parse(Activity activity) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Resources resources = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xmlResourceParser = resources.getXml(R.xml.quotes);
        person = new Pers();
        xmlResourceParser.next();
        int eventType = xmlResourceParser.getEventType();
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xmlResourceParser.getName();
            switch(eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: {
                    if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                        person = new Pers();
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT: {
                    text = xmlResourceParser.getText();
                    break;
                }

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG: {
                    if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                        persons.add(person);
                    } else if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                        person.setId(Integer.parseInt(text));
                    }
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = xmlResourceParser.next();
        }

        return persons;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's this line: `parser.setInput(is, null);`

Because the xml encoding is UTF-8, I believe you have to change it to `parser.setInput(is,"UTF-8");`

Comment: I set utf-8 charset, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in different input to what you have shown us.  Or maybe the source code is different.

- The error message seems to refer to a position that does not exist - line 1, character position 49 (or vice versa).
- The error message seems to indicate some garbled characters (or a string of NULs), but there is nothing problematic in the sample XML.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but, in case it helps anyone else, check:

- There are no characters that need escaping in the XML file e.g. & which should be &#amp;
- Make sure the attributes are correctly enclosed in quotes (in my case, eclipse had been helpful putting close quotes in, so when I added the close quotes at the end of my text, it gave an error

I checked through my XML by starting with the outermost tags, deleting the content and re-adding in bits, running each time, to find where the errors were.  Debugging XML files is a real pain!